# What are WCI reparse points (tag 0x80000018)?

Tags: windows-10-universal, ntfs, internals, reparsepoint

The reparse point tag `0x80000018` has the "Microsoft" bit set, but is not documented [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541667.aspx). This tag is new to Windows 10 and is defined in the SDK as `IO_REPARSE_TAG_WCI`. Information on this is very scarce and the most I could find on it is that it *may* stand for "Windows Container Image" with no explanation as to the tag's function.

Plenty of reparse point tags are mysterious, but what's special about this one is that it is used by some universal apps: when installed, `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\<app>\` contains a `LocalCache` directory which is an `IO_REPARSE_TAG_WCI` reparse point. Inside it is a mostly empty mirror of the user profile directory structure, consisting entirely out of these WCI reparse points.

What is the purpose behind these reparse points? Why do some universal apps use them and others don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCI: Windows Container Isolation

wcifs.sys is the Windows container isolation file system filter driver. For processes running in Windows containers, it provides a view of the virtual file system for that process.